# Prepend hidden field to form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, post

I'm prepending some hidden fields to a form using jQuery, I tried this, which prepends what I need but on submit the form isn't recognising the fields.

So I then manually placed the hidden fields in the page and prepended them to the form (trying it this way because I'm using a form builder).

```
jQuery('<input>').attr({
    type: 'hidden',
    name: 'lm_FormResponsePage',
    value: 'http://oembrocademdf.channelmobile.co/thank-you/'
}).prependTo('.ninja-forms-cont form'); 

jQuery('<input>').attr({
    type: 'hidden',
    name: 'lm_FormKey',
    value: ''
}).prependTo('.ninja-forms-cont form');

jQuery('<input>').attr({
    type: 'hidden',
    name: 'lm_MappingID',
    value: '63'
}).prependTo('.ninja-forms-cont form');

jQuery('<input>').attr({
    type: 'hidden',
    name: 'lm_FormID',
    value: '723'
}).prependTo('.ninja-forms-cont form');

jQuery('<input>').attr({
    type: 'hidden',
    name: 'lm_CompanyID',
    value: '24242'
}).prependTo('.ninja-forms-cont form');
```

But when I submit the form, I get..

*Unable to process form. Neither lm_FormID or lm_MappingID have been set*

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: check what your browser sends to server in network activity tools

Answer (score -1):

This Plunkr might help you. I'm not guessing your HTML. I can help you more if you give your HTML.

Use serialize before sending to the server.

```
var form = $('.ninja-forms-cont form')
var urlParams = $(form).serialize();
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/fdwEqjHNaQvvOAxWcBpU